# JavaCV FFmpegFrameRecorder properties explanation needed

Tags: ffmpeg, javacv

I'm using `FFmpegFrameRecorder` to get the video input from my webcam and record it into a video file. The problem is that I'm building my application using a few different demo source codes that I found and I use properties some of which are not completely clear to me.

First, here is my code snippet :

```
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(FILENAME,  grabber.getImageWidth(),grabber.getImageHeight());

        recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
        recorder.setFormat("mp4");
        recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        recorder.setFrameRate(30);
        recorder.setVideoBitrate(10 * 1024 * 1024);

        recorder.start();
```

- **setVideoCodec(13)** - What is the meaning of this `(13)` how can I understand what actual codec stands behind any number?
- **setPixelFormat** - Just get this, don't know what it's doing in general
- **setFrameRate(30)** - I think this should be pretty clear but still what is the logic behind what frame rate we choose (isn't the high the better?)
- **setVideoBitrate(10*1024*1024)** - again almost no idea what this does and what's the logic behind the numbers?

At the end I just want to mention one last problem that I get recording video like this. If the actual length of the video is let's say 20secs. When I play the video file created from the program it runs significantly faster. Can't tell if it's exactly 2 times faster than it should be but in general if I record a 20sec video then it's played for about 10secs. What may cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**VideoCodec** can be chosen from this list found in `avcodec.h`/`avcodec.java` (As you can see, the number 13 gets us MPEG4, and there are others, but FFmpeg doesn't have an encoder for all of them):

```
    AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO = 1,
    /** preferred ID for MPEG-1/2 video decoding */
    AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO = 2,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO_XVMC = 3,
    AV_CODEC_ID_H261 = 4,
    AV_CODEC_ID_H263 = 5,
    AV_CODEC_ID_RV10 = 6,
    AV_CODEC_ID_RV20 = 7,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG = 8,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEGB = 9,
    AV_CODEC_ID_LJPEG = 10,
    AV_CODEC_ID_SP5X = 11,
    AV_CODEC_ID_JPEGLS = 12,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4 = 13,
    AV_CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO = 14,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V1 = 15,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V2 = 16,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3 = 17,
    AV_CODEC_ID_WMV1 = 18,
    AV_CODEC_ID_WMV2 = 19,
    AV_CODEC_ID_H263P = 20,
    AV_CODEC_ID_H263I = 21,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FLV1 = 22,
    AV_CODEC_ID_SVQ1 = 23,
    AV_CODEC_ID_SVQ3 = 24,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO = 25,
    AV_CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV = 26,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CYUV = 27,
    AV_CODEC_ID_H264 = 28,
    AV_CODEC_ID_INDEO3 = 29,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VP3 = 30,
    AV_CODEC_ID_THEORA = 31,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ASV1 = 32,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ASV2 = 33,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FFV1 = 34,
    AV_CODEC_ID_4XM = 35,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VCR1 = 36,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CLJR = 37,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MDEC = 38,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ROQ = 39,
    AV_CODEC_ID_INTERPLAY_VIDEO = 40,
    AV_CODEC_ID_XAN_WC3 = 41,
    AV_CODEC_ID_XAN_WC4 = 42,
    AV_CODEC_ID_RPZA = 43,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CINEPAK = 44,
    AV_CODEC_ID_WS_VQA = 45,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSRLE = 46,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1 = 47,
    AV_CODEC_ID_IDCIN = 48,
    AV_CODEC_ID_8BPS = 49,
    AV_CODEC_ID_SMC = 50,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FLIC = 51,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION1 = 52,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VMDVIDEO = 53,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSZH = 54,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ZLIB = 55,
    AV_CODEC_ID_QTRLE = 56,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TSCC = 57,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ULTI = 58,
    AV_CODEC_ID_QDRAW = 59,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VIXL = 60,
    AV_CODEC_ID_QPEG = 61,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PNG = 62,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PPM = 63,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PBM = 64,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PGM = 65,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PGMYUV = 66,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PAM = 67,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FFVHUFF = 68,
    AV_CODEC_ID_RV30 = 69,
    AV_CODEC_ID_RV40 = 70,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VC1 = 71,
    AV_CODEC_ID_WMV3 = 72,
    AV_CODEC_ID_LOCO = 73,
    AV_CODEC_ID_WNV1 = 74,
    AV_CODEC_ID_AASC = 75,
    AV_CODEC_ID_INDEO2 = 76,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FRAPS = 77,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION2 = 78,
    AV_CODEC_ID_BMP = 79,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CSCD = 80,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MMVIDEO = 81,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ZMBV = 82,
    AV_CODEC_ID_AVS = 83,
    AV_CODEC_ID_SMACKVIDEO = 84,
    AV_CODEC_ID_NUV = 85,
    AV_CODEC_ID_KMVC = 86,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FLASHSV = 87,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CAVS = 88,
    AV_CODEC_ID_JPEG2000 = 89,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VMNC = 90,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VP5 = 91,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VP6 = 92,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VP6F = 93,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TARGA = 94,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DSICINVIDEO = 95,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TIERTEXSEQVIDEO = 96,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TIFF = 97,
    AV_CODEC_ID_GIF = 98,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DXA = 99,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DNXHD = 100,
    AV_CODEC_ID_THP = 101,
    AV_CODEC_ID_SGI = 102,
    AV_CODEC_ID_C93 = 103,
    AV_CODEC_ID_BETHSOFTVID = 104,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PTX = 105,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TXD = 106,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VP6A = 107,
    AV_CODEC_ID_AMV = 108,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VB = 109,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PCX = 110,
    AV_CODEC_ID_SUNRAST = 111,
    AV_CODEC_ID_INDEO4 = 112,
    AV_CODEC_ID_INDEO5 = 113,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MIMIC = 114,
    AV_CODEC_ID_RL2 = 115,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ESCAPE124 = 116,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DIRAC = 117,
    AV_CODEC_ID_BFI = 118,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CMV = 119,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MOTIONPIXELS = 120,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TGV = 121,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TGQ = 122,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TQI = 123,
    AV_CODEC_ID_AURA = 124,
    AV_CODEC_ID_AURA2 = 125,
    AV_CODEC_ID_V210X = 126,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TMV = 127,
    AV_CODEC_ID_V210 = 128,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DPX = 129,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MAD = 130,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FRWU = 131,
    AV_CODEC_ID_FLASHSV2 = 132,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CDGRAPHICS = 133,
    AV_CODEC_ID_R210 = 134,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ANM = 135,
    AV_CODEC_ID_BINKVIDEO = 136,
    AV_CODEC_ID_IFF_ILBM = 137,
    AV_CODEC_ID_IFF_BYTERUN1 = 138,
    AV_CODEC_ID_KGV1 = 139,
    AV_CODEC_ID_YOP = 140,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VP8 = 141,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PICTOR = 142,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ANSI = 143,
    AV_CODEC_ID_A64_MULTI = 144,
    AV_CODEC_ID_A64_MULTI5 = 145,
    AV_CODEC_ID_R10K = 146,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MXPEG = 147,
    AV_CODEC_ID_LAGARITH = 148,
    AV_CODEC_ID_PRORES = 149,
    AV_CODEC_ID_JV = 150,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DFA = 151,
    AV_CODEC_ID_WMV3IMAGE = 152,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VC1IMAGE = 153,
    AV_CODEC_ID_UTVIDEO = 154,
    AV_CODEC_ID_BMV_VIDEO = 155,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VBLE = 156,
    AV_CODEC_ID_DXTORY = 157,
    AV_CODEC_ID_V410 = 158,
    AV_CODEC_ID_XWD = 159,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CDXL = 160,
    AV_CODEC_ID_XBM = 161,
    AV_CODEC_ID_ZEROCODEC = 162,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSS1 = 163,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSA1 = 164,
    AV_CODEC_ID_TSCC2 = 165,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MTS2 = 166,
    AV_CODEC_ID_CLLC = 167,
    AV_CODEC_ID_MSS2 = 168,
    AV_CODEC_ID_VP9 = 169,
    AV_CODEC_ID_AIC = 170,
    // etc
```

**PixelFormat** can be selected from this list in `pixfmt.h`/`avutil.java`, but each codec only supports a few of them (most of them support at least `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`):

```
    /** planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x2 Y samples) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P = 0,
    /** packed YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, Y0 Cb Y1 Cr */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUYV422 = 1,
    /** packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, RGBRGB... */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 = 2,
    /** packed RGB 8:8:8, 24bpp, BGRBGR... */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24 = 3,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1 Y samples) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P = 4,
    /** planar YUV 4:4:4, 24bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 1x1 Y samples) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P = 5,
    /** planar YUV 4:1:0,  9bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 4x4 Y samples) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV410P = 6,
    /** planar YUV 4:1:1, 12bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 4x1 Y samples) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV411P = 7,
    /**        Y        ,  8bpp */
    AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8 = 8,
    /**        Y        ,  1bpp, 0 is white, 1 is black, in each byte pixels are ordered from the msb to the lsb */
    AV_PIX_FMT_MONOWHITE = 9,
    /**        Y        ,  1bpp, 0 is black, 1 is white, in each byte pixels are ordered from the msb to the lsb */
    AV_PIX_FMT_MONOBLACK = 10,
    /** 8 bit with PIX_FMT_RGB32 palette */
    AV_PIX_FMT_PAL8 = 11,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp, full scale (JPEG), deprecated in favor of PIX_FMT_YUV420P and setting color_range */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P = 12,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, full scale (JPEG), deprecated in favor of PIX_FMT_YUV422P and setting color_range */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P = 13,
    /** planar YUV 4:4:4, 24bpp, full scale (JPEG), deprecated in favor of PIX_FMT_YUV444P and setting color_range */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ444P = 14,
    /** XVideo Motion Acceleration via common packet passing */
    AV_PIX_FMT_XVMC_MPEG2_MC = 15,
    AV_PIX_FMT_XVMC_MPEG2_IDCT = 16;
    /** packed YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, Cb Y0 Cr Y1 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422 = 17,
    /** packed YUV 4:1:1, 12bpp, Cb Y0 Y1 Cr Y2 Y3 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_UYYVYY411 = 18,
    /** packed RGB 3:3:2,  8bpp, (msb)2B 3G 3R(lsb) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR8 = 19,
    /** packed RGB 1:2:1 bitstream,  4bpp, (msb)1B 2G 1R(lsb), a byte contains two pixels, the first pixel in the byte is the one composed by the 4 msb bits */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR4 = 20,
    /** packed RGB 1:2:1,  8bpp, (msb)1B 2G 1R(lsb) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR4_BYTE = 21,
    /** packed RGB 3:3:2,  8bpp, (msb)2R 3G 3B(lsb) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB8 = 22,
    /** packed RGB 1:2:1 bitstream,  4bpp, (msb)1R 2G 1B(lsb), a byte contains two pixels, the first pixel in the byte is the one composed by the 4 msb bits */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB4 = 23,
    /** packed RGB 1:2:1,  8bpp, (msb)1R 2G 1B(lsb) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB4_BYTE = 24,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp, 1 plane for Y and 1 plane for the UV components, which are interleaved (first byte U and the following byte V) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_NV12 = 25,
    /** as above, but U and V bytes are swapped */
    AV_PIX_FMT_NV21 = 26,

    /** packed ARGB 8:8:8:8, 32bpp, ARGBARGB... */
    AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB = 27,
    /** packed RGBA 8:8:8:8, 32bpp, RGBARGBA... */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA = 28,
    /** packed ABGR 8:8:8:8, 32bpp, ABGRABGR... */
    AV_PIX_FMT_ABGR = 29,
    /** packed BGRA 8:8:8:8, 32bpp, BGRABGRA... */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA = 30,

    /**        Y        , 16bpp, big-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY16BE = 31,
    /**        Y        , 16bpp, little-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY16LE = 32,
    /** planar YUV 4:4:0 (1 Cr & Cb sample per 1x2 Y samples) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV440P = 33,
    /** planar YUV 4:4:0 full scale (JPEG), deprecated in favor of PIX_FMT_YUV440P and setting color_range */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ440P = 34,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:0, 20bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x2 Y & A samples) */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUVA420P = 35,
    /** H.264 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_H264 = 36,
    /** MPEG-1 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG1 = 37,
    /** MPEG-2 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG2 = 38,
    /** WMV3 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_WMV3 = 39,
    /** VC-1 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_VC1 = 40,
    /** packed RGB 16:16:16, 48bpp, 16R, 16G, 16B, the 2-byte value for each R/G/B component is stored as big-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB48BE = 41,
    /** packed RGB 16:16:16, 48bpp, 16R, 16G, 16B, the 2-byte value for each R/G/B component is stored as little-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB48LE = 42,

    /** packed RGB 5:6:5, 16bpp, (msb)   5R 6G 5B(lsb), big-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565BE = 43,
    /** packed RGB 5:6:5, 16bpp, (msb)   5R 6G 5B(lsb), little-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565LE = 44,
    /** packed RGB 5:5:5, 16bpp, (msb)1A 5R 5G 5B(lsb), big-endian, most significant bit to 0 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB555BE = 45,
    /** packed RGB 5:5:5, 16bpp, (msb)1A 5R 5G 5B(lsb), little-endian, most significant bit to 0 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB555LE = 46,

    /** packed BGR 5:6:5, 16bpp, (msb)   5B 6G 5R(lsb), big-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR565BE = 47,
    /** packed BGR 5:6:5, 16bpp, (msb)   5B 6G 5R(lsb), little-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR565LE = 48,
    /** packed BGR 5:5:5, 16bpp, (msb)1A 5B 5G 5R(lsb), big-endian, most significant bit to 1 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR555BE = 49,
    /** packed BGR 5:5:5, 16bpp, (msb)1A 5B 5G 5R(lsb), little-endian, most significant bit to 1 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR555LE = 50,

    /** HW acceleration through VA API at motion compensation entry-point, Picture.data[3] contains a vaapi_render_state struct which contains macroblocks as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VAAPI_MOCO = 51,
    /** HW acceleration through VA API at IDCT entry-point, Picture.data[3] contains a vaapi_render_state struct which contains fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VAAPI_IDCT = 52,
    /** HW decoding through VA API, Picture.data[3] contains a vaapi_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VAAPI_VLD = 53,

    /** planar YUV 4:2:0, 24bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x2 Y samples), little-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P16LE = 54,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:0, 24bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x2 Y samples), big-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P16BE = 55,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:2, 32bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1 Y samples), little-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P16LE = 56,
    /** planar YUV 4:2:2, 32bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1 Y samples), big-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P16BE = 57,
    /** planar YUV 4:4:4, 48bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 1x1 Y samples), little-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P16LE = 58,
    /** planar YUV 4:4:4, 48bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 1x1 Y samples), big-endian */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P16BE = 59,
    /** MPEG4 HW decoding with VDPAU, data[0] contains a vdpau_render_state struct which contains the bitstream of the slices as well as various fields extracted from headers */
    AV_PIX_FMT_VDPAU_MPEG4 = 60,
    /** HW decoding through DXVA2, Picture.data[3] contains a LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pointer */
    AV_PIX_FMT_DXVA2_VLD = 61,

    /** packed RGB 4:4:4, 16bpp, (msb)4A 4R 4G 4B(lsb), little-endian, most significant bits to 0 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB444LE = 62,
    /** packed RGB 4:4:4, 16bpp, (msb)4A 4R 4G 4B(lsb), big-endian, most significant bits to 0 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB444BE = 63,
    /** packed BGR 4:4:4, 16bpp, (msb)4A 4B 4G 4R(lsb), little-endian, most significant bits to 1 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR444LE = 64,
    /** packed BGR 4:4:4, 16bpp, (msb)4A 4B 4G 4R(lsb), big-endian, most significant bits to 1 */
    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR444BE = 65,
    /** 8bit gray, 8bit alpha */
    AV_PIX_FMT_YA8 = 66,
    // etc
```

**FrameRate** indicates the number of frames per second the video should be played back at (it has nothing to do with the number or the timing of images you actually record, although it provides a basis for the encoding bitrate). So, in the case of 30 FPS, to cover 20 seconds of video, you need to call `record()` 30 * 20 = 600 times. If you do no call `record()` 600 times, then this is the cause of your problem.

**VideoBitrate** provides the video bitrate (in bits per second) at which the video stream should be encoded at. Wikipedia has [a nice article about that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate).

Comment: Thanks, Samuel nice answer. Appreciate.

Comment: Sure! BTW, some codecs (FLV1 and MPEG4 maybe?) support variable frame rates, which we get when calling `setTimestamp(playbackTimeInMicroseconds)` before each `record(image)`. That can help when it's not possible to achieve a steady frame rate for whatever reason.

Comment: Hi wonderful explanation.Can you please describe about timestamp mechanism.How to set timestamp your video in FFmpegFrameRecorder?

Comment: @Dipu There is an example of that in the [RecordActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/RecordActivity.java) sample. That should clear up a few things regarding timestamps.

Comment: @SamuelAudet I have seen it already Actually in my case audio comes faster than video frame.I have posted this have look and suggest me what's wrong .Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342732/ffmpegframerecorder-videobroadcasting-audio-comes-faster-than-video-frame

Comment: @SamuelAudet: how to set animation to each frame like zoomIn, zoomOut
is it possible in android ?

Comment: @V.P. `avfilter` can do that and is in there, but JavaCV doesn't come with any high-level API for that unfortunately.

Comment: @SamuelAudet can you please send me document regarding avfilter? so i will do.