# FFmpegFrameRecorder videoBroadcasting audio comes faster than video frame in 3G Network

Tags: android, javacv, video-recording

I'm using `FFmpegFrameRecorder` for video broadcast.Problem is audio comes faster than video frame.I'm using following code but unable to produce complete video there is problem in audio video timestamp.

**Java Code:**

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    private String ffmpeg_link = "";

    private volatile FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;
    boolean recording = false;
    long startTime = 0;

    private int sampleAudioRateInHz = 16000;
    private int imageWidth = 320;
    private int imageHeight = 240;
    private int frameRate = 24;

    private Thread audioThread;
    volatile boolean runAudioThread = true;
    private AudioRecord audioRecord;
    private AudioRecordRunnable audioRecordRunnable;

    private CameraView cameraView;
    private IplImage yuvIplimage = null;

    private Button recordButton;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initLayout();
        initRecorder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mWakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK,
                    LOG_TAG);
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        recording = false;
    }

    private void initLayout() {

        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.record_layout);

        recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recorder_control);
        recordButton.setText("Start");
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        cameraView = new CameraView(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainLayout.addView(cameraView, layoutParam);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "added cameraView to mainLayout");
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "initRecorder");

        if (yuvIplimage == null) {
            // Recreated after frame size is set in surface change method
            yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                    IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
            // yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight,
            // IPL_DEPTH_32S, 2);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "IplImage.create");
        }

        recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageWidth,
                imageHeight, 1);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "FFmpegFrameRecorder: " + ffmpeg_link + " imageWidth: "
                + imageWidth + " imageHeight " + imageHeight);

        recorder.setFormat("flv");
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "recorder.setFormat(\"flv\")");

        recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz)");

        // re-set in the surface changed method as well
        recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate)");

        // Create audio recording thread
        audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
        audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
    }

    // Start the capture
    public void startRecording() {
        try {
            recorder.start();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            recording = true;
            audioThread.start();
        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        // This should stop the audio thread from running
        runAudioThread = false;

        if (recorder != null && recording) {
            recording = false;
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                    "Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Quit when back button is pushed
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (recording) {
                stopRecording();
            }
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!recording) {
            startRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Start Button Pushed");
            recordButton.setText("Stop");
        } else {
            stopRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Stop Button Pushed");
            recordButton.setText("Start");
        }
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // audio thread, gets and encodes audio data
    // ---------------------------------------------
    class AudioRecordRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Set the thread priority
            android.os.Process
                    .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            // Audio
            int bufferSize;
            short[] audioData;
            int bufferReadResult;

            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioRateInHz,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    sampleAudioRateInHz,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

            audioData = new short[bufferSize];

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord.startRecording()");
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            // Audio Capture/Encoding Loop
            while (runAudioThread) {
                // Read from audioRecord
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0,
                        audioData.length);
                if (bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"audioRecord bufferReadResult: " +
                    // bufferReadResult);

                    // Changes in this variable may not be picked up despite it
                    // being "volatile"
                    if (recording) {
                        try {
                            // Write to FFmpegFrameRecorder
                            recorder.record(ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 0,
                                    bufferReadResult));
                        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "AudioThread Finished");

            /* Capture/Encoding finished, release recorder */
            if (audioRecord != null) {
                audioRecord.stop();
                audioRecord.release();
                audioRecord = null;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord released");
            }
        }
    }

    class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
            PreviewCallback {

        private boolean previewRunning = false;

        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private Camera camera;

        private byte[] previewBuffer;

        long videoTimestamp = 0;

        Bitmap bitmap;
        Canvas canvas;

        public CameraView(Context _context) {
            super(_context);

            holder = this.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera = Camera.open();

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.setPreviewCallback(this);

                Camera.Parameters currentParams = camera.getParameters();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                        "Preview Framerate: "
                                + currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                        "Preview imageWidth: "
                                + currentParams.getPreviewSize().width
                                + " imageHeight: "
                                + currentParams.getPreviewSize().height);

                // Use these values
                imageWidth = currentParams.getPreviewSize().width;
                imageHeight = currentParams.getPreviewSize().height;
                frameRate = currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate();

                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                        Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);

                /*
                 * Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Creating previewBuffer size: " + imageWidth *
                 * imageHeight *
                 * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(currentParams.getPreviewFormat
                 * ())/8); previewBuffer = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight *
                 * ImageFormat
                 * .getBitsPerPixel(currentParams.getPreviewFormat())/8];
                 * camera.addCallbackBuffer(previewBuffer);
                 * camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
                 */

                camera.startPreview();
                previewRunning = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Surface Changed: width " + width + " height: "
                    + height);

            // We would do this if we want to reset the camera parameters
            /*
             * if (!recording) { if (previewRunning){ camera.stopPreview(); }
             * 
             * try { //Camera.Parameters cameraParameters =
             * camera.getParameters(); //p.setPreviewSize(imageWidth,
             * imageHeight); //p.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
             * //camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
             * 
             * camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); camera.startPreview();
             * previewRunning = true; } catch (IOException e) {
             * Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); } }
             */

            // Get the current parameters
            Camera.Parameters currentParams = camera.getParameters();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                    "Preview Framerate: " + currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                    "Preview imageWidth: "
                            + currentParams.getPreviewSize().width
                            + " imageHeight: "
                            + currentParams.getPreviewSize().height);

            // Use these values
            imageWidth = currentParams.getPreviewSize().width;
            imageHeight = currentParams.getPreviewSize().height;
            frameRate = currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate();

            // Create the yuvIplimage if needed
            yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                    IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            // yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight,
            // IPL_DEPTH_32S, 2);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

                previewRunning = false;
                camera.release();

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
                videoTimestamp = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

                // Put the camera preview frame right into the yuvIplimage
                // object
                System.out.println("value of data=============" + data);
                yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

                // FAQ about IplImage:
                // - For custom raw processing of data, getByteBuffer() returns
                // an NIO direct
                // buffer wrapped around the memory pointed by imageData, and
                // under Android we can
                // also use that Buffer with Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer() and
                // copyPixelsToBuffer().
                // - To get a BufferedImage from an IplImage, we may call
                // getBufferedImage().
                // - The createFrom() factory method can construct an IplImage
                // from a BufferedImage.
                // - There are also a few copy*() methods for
                // BufferedImage<->IplImage data transfers.

                // Let's try it..
                // This works but only on transparency
                // Need to find the right Bitmap and IplImage matching types

                /*
                 * bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer());
                 * //bitmap.setPixel(10,10,Color.MAGENTA);
                 * 
                 * canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); Paint paint = new Paint();
                 * paint.setColor(Color.GREEN); float leftx = 20; float topy =
                 * 20; float rightx = 50; float bottomy = 100; RectF rectangle =
                 * new RectF(leftx,topy,rightx,bottomy);
                 * canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
                 * 
                 * bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer());
                 */
                // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Writing Frame");

                try {

                    // Get the correct time
                    recorder.setTimestamp(videoTimestamp);

                    // Record the image into FFmpegFrameRecorder
                    recorder.record(yuvIplimage);

                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.javacv.stream.test2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.javacv.stream.test2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "comes faster"? Do you get broken audio? Or are they simply out of sync? In any case, it's likely that your device just isn't fast enough to encode in real time: Did you try to reduce the bitrate by calling `FrameRecorder.setVideoBitrate()` before `start()` to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @SamuelAudet I have already used all the process but it's not working for me recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
   recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_FLV1);
   recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
   recorder.setVideoBitrate(1200);
   recorder.setAudioBitrate(80);

Comment: Other people on the mailing list are having the same issue with some of their devices only. It seems to be related to something that happens only on certain devices...

Comment: So how come you do not access the encoded stream directly?

Comment: @ThomasRS I'm accessing encoded stream using streaming server and it's working fine on wifi network but in 3g speed audio came faster than video frames

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue we battled with on the iOS side as well.. Basically the packets for video get dropped while the audio keeps going, and it all goes to hell. Some hardware under low bandwidth just doesn't play nice and goes out of sync.. I don't believe there is a solid fix, we had to hack it by building our own buffer on top for the audio/video and re-synchronizing using timestamps, frame sizes, and packet counts.

Afraid I can't post that code (it's not mine to post) but if you know the protocol, shouldn't be hard to recreate..

Comment: Thank it's really helpful But I have tried the same and didn't get solution so can you elaborate this Thanks