# FFmpegFrameRecorder calls record() 20 times but the resulting mp4 file only has 2 frames

Tags: ffmpeg, javacv

I'm using FFmpegFrameRecorder to create mp4(H264) video from camera preview. My recorder configuration is as follows.

```
recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(filePath, width, height);
recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
recorder.setFormat("mp4");
recorder.setFrameRate(VIDEO_FPS);
recorder.setVideoBitrate(16384);
recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
```

For the rest I follows closely to the sample code RecordActivity.java and was able to verify that

```
recorder.record(yuvIplimage)
```

gets called 20 (or more) times, which should create an mp4 with 20 frames. However, the resulting mp4 files after open up only has 2 frames (two first frame of the preview)! I have no idea what have caused such behavior. Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you.

Long Le

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: the issue was because I didn't know what I was doing. I was new to javacv, and I was assuming, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125758/javacv-ffmpegframerecorder-properties-explanation-needed) stackoverflow entry, that the number of frames in the resulting video should be equal to the number of record() calls. However, this is not the case with video encoding, especially with H264. I figured this out by trying with MPEG4 encoding and there's definitely more than 2 frames. H264 seems to require a [minimum number of input frames](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=302) and hence is not suitable for short (<1 minute) video clips generation (which is my application). One solution is to switch to MPEG4 encoding. However, most browser that does play .mp4 files does not support MPEG4 encoding. Another the solution is to use H264 with minimize compression, by adding the following configuration

```
recorder.setVideoQuality(0); // maximum quality, replace recorder.setVideoBitrate(16384);
recorder.setVideoOption("preset", "veryfast"); // or ultrafast or fast, etc.
```