# Youtube doesn't accept the mp4 I generate with javacv from an mp3 and a jpeg

Tags: java, youtube-api, mp3, mp4, javacv

Youtube doesn't accept the mp4 I generatewith javacv from an mp3 and a jpeg

I am using the youtube java api to upload this and no exception is thrown while uploading. An error which I pasted below occurs when only when I go to the youtube site. Either to see the uploaded video or to upload the video by hand.
The mp4 file is 00:59 in length and 506 kb in size so I don't thing that should be an issue.

This is the code:

```
public static void MergeMp3Mp4JavaCv(String path2ImageFile,String path2AudioFile, String path2OutputFile) throws IOException
    {

        IplImage ipl = cvLoadImage(path2ImageFile);
        int height = ipl.height();
        int width = ipl.width();
        if(height%2!=0) height = height+1;
        if(width%2!=0) width = width+1;

        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();  
        FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path2OutputFile,width,height); 
        FrameGrabber audioFileGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path2AudioFile);
        try 
        {  
            audioFileGrabber.start();

            recorder.setFrameRate(1);  
            recorder.setVideoBitrate(audioFileGrabber.getAudioBitrate());  
            recorder.setFormat("mp4");  
            recorder.setAudioChannels(1);
            recorder.start();  

            recorder.record(grabberConverter.convert(ipl));  
            Frame frame = null;
            while ((frame = audioFileGrabber.grabFrame())!=null) 
            {
                recorder.record(frame);
            }

            recorder.stop();  
            audioFileGrabber.stop();
         }  
         catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception e){  
           e.printStackTrace();  
         }  
    }
```

Youtube says:

> The video has failed to process. Please make sure you are uploading a
>   supported file type.

Edit: the file plays flawlessly in windows media player
Edit 2:
I checked out
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en

```
Audio codec: AAC-LC
Channels: Stereo or Stereo + 5.1
Sample rate 96khz or 48khz

Video codec: H.264
Progressive scan (no interlacing)
High Profile
2 consecutive B frames
Closed GOP. GOP of half the frame rate.
CABAC
Variable bitrate. No bitrate limit required, though we offer recommended bit rates below for reference
Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0
```

I tried

```
recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264 );
recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
```

Tried a lot of other video codecs as well, but nothing works.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the video play on your media player?

Comment: @j_d yes, it does, I edited the question, sorry for not mentioning this

Comment: That's OK.YouTube video uploads could fail for many reasons. This maybe related to the codec used for the mp4. Maybe some research into the accepted codec for YouTube video's would help.

Comment: In this context sed codec would be opencv, right?

Comment: No, it is not. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125758/javacv-ffmpegframerecorder-properties-explanation-needed) question on how to set a codec for FFmpegFrameRecorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to get it working like this

```
public static void MergeMp3AndJpegIntoMp4(String path2ImageFile,String path2AudioFile, String path2OutputFile) throws IOException
    {

        IplImage ipl = cvLoadImage(path2ImageFile);
        int height = ipl.height();
        int width = ipl.width();
        if(height%2!=0) height = height+1;
        if(width%2!=0) width = width+1;

        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();  
        FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path2OutputFile,width,height); 
        FrameGrabber audioFileGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path2AudioFile);
        try 
        {  
            audioFileGrabber.start();

            recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264 );//AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS
            recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);//AV_CODEC_ID_MP3 //AV_CODEC_ID_AAC

            recorder.setFormat("mp4");  
            recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
            recorder.start();  

            Frame frame = null;
            while ((frame = audioFileGrabber.grabFrame())!=null) 
            {   recorder.record(grabberConverter.convert(ipl));  
                recorder.record(frame);
            }

            recorder.stop();  
            audioFileGrabber.stop();
         }  
         catch (org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception e){  
           e.printStackTrace();  
           throw e;
         }  

    }
```